# Executing npm install in user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, user-data, launch-template

I am attempting to create a launch template in aws with the following in the user data

```
#!/bin/bash
home=/home/ec2-user
nodev='8.11.2'
nvmv='0.33.11'

#install node
su - ec2-user -c "curl 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v${nvmv}/install.sh | bash"
su - ec2-user -c "nvm install ${nodev}"
su - ec2-user -c "nvm use ${nodev}"

# install git
yum install git -y

#clone the code
cd /home/ec2-user
su - ec2-user -c "git clone https://github.com/xyz/xdf.git"
cd /home/ec2-user/xdf

#install dependencies
su - ec2-user -c "npm install"
echo "test" > test.txt

#install pm2
su - ec2-user -c "npm install pm2 -g"

#run the server
su - ec2-user -c "pm2 run index.js"
```

The script is being executed and the repo is cloned but the npm install command is running on the dir /home/ec2-user rather than on /home/ec2-user/xdf. The test.txt is created in the correct place ie inside /home/ec2-user/xdf. How do I get npm install to run on /home/ec2-user/xdf. I tried just running `npm install` instead of `su - ec2-user -c "npm install"`, but it still giving the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `userdata` is running with `root` user permissions so you don't need to have `sudo` or `su` there. In case you want `ec2-user` to be owner of that dir so simply execute `chown ec2-user:ec2-user /path/to/dir`

Next, when you run `su - ec2-user -c ...` it is executed in `/home/ec2-user` dir and `cd /home/ec2-user/xdf` is not working here.
Simply remove all `su` from your script